# Metodo main e JUnit nao roda no console

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou usando as versão 2.1 JPA, do Hibernate versao 5, e quando rodo tanto o metodo main como o JUnit, nada aparece
no console nem mesmo algum erro. A classe cliente e endereço contem seus ids.

Nem o System aparece no console.
    System.out.println("Teste");

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="PedidoPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cursojavaee" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Hibernate

```
<!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Teste

public class Teste {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidoPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction trx = em.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.setNome("Paulo da Paz");
    cliente.setEmail("paulopaz@paulopaz.com.br");
    cliente.setDocumentoReceitaFederal("000.000.000-00");
    cliente.setTipo(TipoPessoa.FISICA);

    Endereco endereco = new Endereco();
    endereco.setLogradouro("Rua dos Anjos Branco");
    endereco.setComplemento("APTO 001");
    endereco.setNumero("111");
    endereco.setCidade("Luziânia");
    endereco.setUf("GO");
    endereco.setCep("72800000");
    endereco.setCliente(cliente);

    cliente.getEnderecos().add(endereco);

    em.persist(cliente);

    trx.commit();
}
```

Cliente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String nome;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

get e set pra nome

Endereço

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "endereco")
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String logradouro;
private String numero;
private String complemento;
private String cidade;
private String uf;
private String cep;
private Cliente cliente;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

todos get e set

Comment: Poderia postar as classes `Cliente` e `Endereco`?

Comment: Postei, nem o  System.out.println("Teste"); aparece no console, ja troquei de IDE e nada.